# How to log every single API request in python flask and visualise them easily

Tags: python, flask, logging, analytics

is there a solution that allows to easily log every request in python flask to some DB and then allows the whole team to query them?

I would prefer a solution that allows minimal work when building things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@after_request is pretty helpful for this

I'd recommend collecting your response statistics in a db, so the decorator would look something like this:

```
@app.after_request
def log_requests(resp):
    log_to_db(request=request, response=resp)
```

and then the function log_to_db will do whatever you want with the request and response objects - log their duration, sizes, increment the times this endpoint was called, etc...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build a decorator and apply it to each request method. The decorator will accept some common to request params and log them into the log DB.

Maybe if you want to decorate 10000 request handlers it would not be a simple way. In that case have a look at https://medium.com/innovation-incubator/flask-before-and-after-request-decorators-e639b06c2128 maybe you get inspired.